# Check checkbox when specific sibling elements are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to check the checkbox in the third TD when the first or third TD is clicked, but not when the second TD is clicked. Here is my code that I can't get to work:

```
<tr class="item" id="sku999">
      <td>Hat</td>
      <td class="valueButton"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="10.00"></td>
</tr>

$(document).on({
    click: function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('blueChecked');
        $(this).prevAll.toggleClass('blueChecked');
        $(this).nextAll.toggleClass('blueChecked');
        if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
            $(':checkbox', this.parent()).attr('checked', function() {
                return !this.checked;
            });
        }
    }
}, "tr.item td:not('.valueButton')");
```

**UPDATE**: I forgot to mention I need to be able to toggle the checkbox.

**UPDATE**: Solved!

```
$(document).on({
    click: function () {
        $("td:not('.valueButton')", $(this).parent()).toggleClass('blueChecked');

        if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
            $(':checkbox', $(this).parent()).attr('checked', function() {
                return !this.checked;
            });
        }
    }
}, "tr.item td:not('.valueButton')");
```

Comment: Try using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`, and also you don't need callback here, you can simply write `$(':checkbox', this.parent()).prop('checked',!this.checked)`

Comment: Thanks, that half works, however it only works when checking the checkbox, it doesn't work on the second click to uncheck: `$(':checkbox', $(this).parent()).prop('checked', !$(this).checked);`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I need to be able to toggle the checkbox, which is the problem I'm having now.

Comment: Figured it out and updated my initial post. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('td:not(:nth-child(1))').click(function{
             $('td:nth-child(2) checkbox').prop('checked',true);
    });
```